# How to find MIN/MAX using window functions with NO correlated sub-queries?

Tags: sql

My goal is to select the closest DocumentDate to each InvoiceDate with some constraints. The   DocumentDate must be before the InvoiceDate and any DocumentDate cannot be selected more than once (ordered by InvoiceDate DESC).

So I've my first table contains clients and all their invoices. My second table contains all the documents found in the client folder with an extracted date from the file name. I'm using Zoho Analytics, which only allows select statements and does not support correlated sub-queries. Please share your suggestions!

Invoices:

```
Client  InvoiceDate
1       7/3/2021
1       6/1/2021
1       3/2/2021
```

Documents:

```
Client  DocumentDate
1       7/20/2021
1       5/29/2021
1       5/10/2021
1       2/9/2021
```

My desired output can be obtained by beginning with the largest invoiceDate.

- For 7/3/21, the pool of documents to select from will be (5/29/2021, 5/10/2021, 2/9/2021) with 7/20/21 excluded because it is larger than the InvoiceDate. I want to select 5/29/21 since that is the largest in the selection pool.
- For 6/1/21 the pool to select from will be (5/10/2021, 2/9/2021) with  5/29/21 excluded because it was the chosen document for InvoiceDate 7/3/21 and 7/20/21 excluded because it is larger than the InvoiceDate. I want to select 5/10/2021 because it is the largest in the selection pool.
- For 3/2/21 the pool to select from will be (2/9/2021) with 7/20/21, 5/29/21, 5/10/21 excluded because they are larger than the InvoiceDate. 2/9/2021 would be selected since it is the only entry left in the selection pool.

Desired Output

```
Client  InvoiceDate DocumentDate
1       7/3/2021    5/29/2021
1       6/1/2021    5/10/2021
1       3/2/2021    2/9/2021
```

Comment: From the ZOHO documentation, *Zoho Analytics supports full-fledged SQL based querying of your database. It understands SQL SELECT Queries written in any of the well-known database dialects including Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2, Sybase, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Informix and ANSI SQL* - so where does the inability to use a subquery come from, that's standard SQL?

Comment: It only has the inability to use correlated subqueries. So any inside query can't see anything from the outside query, if that makes sense

Comment: That makes sense, but that also contradicts the description quoted above that claims it's "full-fledged" - if you cannot write correlated queries it cannot be fully fledged! Can you use common table expressions?

Comment: One SQL grammar for Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2, Sybase, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Informix _and_ ANSI SQL?!? That would be huge, but I don't think it's possible, too many clashes.

Comment: Indeed, I would be highly dubious of something with such claims, yet lacked core language functionality.